# simple suggested script not working

Tags: autohotkey

I'm completely new to AutoHotKey.

I liked the idea of setting caps lock to only go on if the shift key is pressed first, so I followed these directions and copied the following into my script ([from this page](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm))

```
Capslock::Ctrl
```

It makes Capslock become a Control key. To retain the ability to turn Capslock on and off, also add the remapping `+Capslock::Capslock` (this toggles Capslock on and off when you hold down the shift key and press Capslock)."

I succeeded in getting the caps lock key to work as a Ctrl key, , but when I press Shift + Capslock, it doesn't do anything.

Can someone please explain why it is not working and tell me what I need to do to get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run the following code it runs fine.

```
+Capslock::Capslock
$Capslock::Ctrl
```

Could you try this as well?

Comment: Thank you! That works. Could you possibly explain why, and why the other didn't work?

Comment: You First told the system to Change CapsLock into Ctrl and THEN you instructed it to change (the modyfied) Capslock with shift to behave like Capslock. In your situation pressing Shift Capslock actually created Shift (is not ignored here) and Control. Switching it around fixed it and putting a $ in front of CapsLock prevents it from being triggered by the first code.

Comment: Please provide some feedback on the proposed solution and if the answer was helpful, then please "Accept" that answer by clicking on the white check-mark to turn it green. Thank you!

Comment: The answer was helpful. Then please "Accept" that answer by clicking on the white check-mark next to the answer. This will mark the question solved and give the right credits. For the details see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/210367